# Access inputs from separate forms in Laravel using form collective

Tags: laravel

I am very new to Laravel. On my blade I have to forms, First has 11 checkboxes and save button. Basically a user comes to check inputs he needed and clicks save, which takes to controller and stores the values. Now, I have 'accept' button which is completely separate function in controller, but I still need the values from input fields. How would I pass the values from different form.

Example:

```
{{ Form::checkbox('shopping['.$current->id.']', true, $shopping_cart->getPresence($current->id), ['disabled']) }}

{!! Form::button('<i class="fas fa-btn fa-save"></i>Save', ['type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}
            </div>
        @endif
        {!! Form::close() !!}

{!! Form::model($shipping, [ 'method' => 'POST', 'action' => ['Shopping@storeAcceptShipping', $shopping->id]]) !!}
{!! Form::close !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use hidden fields y another form. When you send the first form, get in Controller with a standard request and serialize the data like:

```
$data_form1_serialized = serialize($request->all());
```

after return the view with this serialized data

```
return view('form2',compact("data_form1_serialized");
```

In view form2 make a hidden input with value $data_form1_serialized

```php
{!! Form::model($shipping, [ 'method' => 'POST', 'action' => ['Shopping@storeAcceptShipping', $shopping->id]]) !!}
{!! Form::hidden('data_form1', $data_form1_serialized) !!}
{!! Form::close !!}
```

OR

Use Vue or(something JS) display a form with tabs o a form step by step, and when all the form is complete part1, part2 etc. Send to Controller. This is for me the right way.